# Cloud9が使用出来ない

Tags: aws-cloud9

cloud9に接続しようとしても以下のエラーが発生し、使用することが出来ません。

・EC2インスタンスの再起動
・インスタンスタイプの変更
等は試しました。

何か解決策はありますでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

This is taking longer than expected. The delay may be caused by high CPU usage in your environment, or your T2 or T3 instance is running out of burstable CPU capacity credits, or there are VPC configuration issues. Please check documentation.

追記-----------------------------------

現在のインスタンスタイプ
m4.large（元はt2 small, 他にもt2midium, t2xlarge, t3smallを試しました）

VPCの設定に関しては２つのＡＺに分けて構築していますが、Ｃ９用に使用しているのサブネットＡー１で、Ｃ９用が６台を配備されています。

ネットワークに関しては、ＡＣＬでそれぞれのサブネットを繋いでいます。

Comment: この情報だけだと、推測で回答するほかなさそうです。もっと詳細な情報を追記いただけますでしょうか、ネットワークの設定やVPCの設定状況どのようなインスタンスを利用していてどのようなインスタンスに変更しようとしたのか？再現性が取れるような手順を示していただけるとより回答が集まりやすいでしょう。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
わかる範囲で追記しましたので、ご確認頂けますでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。